# what is the best 3D java renderer?

Tags: java, 3d

I need a 3D rendering engine that is easy to learn, and modern styled (not like java3d). I've tried lwjgl and jmonkeyengine but i find them really confusing. What other good engines are there?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No 3D renderers are easy. You will have a lot to learn regardless of which one you choose.

You have probably already found the best two:

- LWJGL is basically a fairly thin wrapper for OpenGL. Lots of game developers like to use OpenGL, so it is a pretty good choice if you are in that camp. Use it if you want speed and control, and don't mind building a few "engine" parts yourself.
- jMonkeyEngine is a more complete game engine. Use it if you want to get up and running with a full 3D engine pretty quickly. It uses LWJGL underneath, but adds layers on top of it (like a scene graph) so you don't need to use OpenGL directly.

In your case I'd probably go for jMonkeyEngine - I think it's a bit "friendlier".

Alternatively there is [Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/), which is great for making 2D games if you decide that you don't really want to wrestle with the learning curve of going 3D.

Answer (score 1):

JMonkeyEngine is actually rather simple to learn as far as 3D libraries go if you follow it through properly - you'll struggle to find a fully featured 3D engine that's simpler.

Read up on scene graphs first, a proper understanding of them is critical to understand how JME works - then try following some of the [basic tutorials](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3%3abeginner) through (of which there are quite a few.)

If you still struggle with that, it may be that you need to familiarise yourself more with Java (or programming) in general. You may want to give [Greenfoot](http://greenfoot.org) a try if you want to start with 2D games and work up - it provides an easy IDE / framework for creating and sharing 2D games in Java.

Oh and I agree with staying away from Java3D - it's rather old now and pretty unsupported.